# Basic Jquery- Fade Out/Fade In

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a very basic guessing game using jquery and html. I have 6 checkboxes, and if the right sequence is triggered, a hidden div appears. In order to trigger the div, I need to select 1,2,and 3. If you select 1,2,and 4, you get a secret message (div2), and otherwise nothing happens.

I can do the trigger easily by doing nested clicks:

```
 $("#1").click(function(){
  $("#2").click(function(){
   $("#3").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeIn();
 });
 });
 });
```

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="#1">
<input type="checkbox" id="#2">
<input type="checkbox" id="#3">
<input type="checkbox" id="#4">
<input type="checkbox" id="#5">
<input type="checkbox" id="#6">
<div id="div1" style="width:30px;height:30px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div>
<div id="div2" style="width:30px;height:30px;display:none;background-color:yellow;"></div>
```

But I am having trouble making it disappear. 
If any one of the three is not pressed, I would like for that div to disappear. So let's say you press 1,2,3, div1 appears, and if you deselect 3, that div1 disappears.

I think I can make the question easier to phrase by phrasing it like this: i want to tell jquery- if one, and two, and three, are not 'all' selected, fade out the div.

Comment: like what to disappear? also please share the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using nested clicks, which will get complicated and confusing, you'd be better off creating a generalised listener that will maintain a list of what has/hasn't been clicked. Not only is this easier to maintain, it is also more optimal than having many click handlers assigned.

Others out there who may wish to optimise further may say correctly that you could write this code to directly generate a `checked` array, rather than a `checked` object, the reason I have kept it as an object is to support the possibility of a string-based `ident` rather than just numerical.

#### updated code

Previous code was slightly buggy, this version now works correctly when you select more checkboxes than you should.

#### reasons why

1. **why change to use classes more than ids**

   Whilst ids are very specific, and will be more optimal for the browser to select by, they generally cause confusion and make things laborious, especially in markup that you wish to duplicate (obviously because ids have to be unique). It is often far better to come up with a solution that can work on a general grouping class, than having to label each element with a sequence i.e. cb1, cb2, cb3. As you can see my markup does label the checkboxes sequentially but the code only worries about the grouping class `.cb`, leaving the sequential classes really only for css styling.
2. **why add a container div**

   When working on html5 apps, container divs will help you out 9 times out of 10. If you have a collection of elements that will only ever reside in a close visual formation, you will do yourself a favour by wrapping them. This helps when dynamically generating more elements (you can append your new elements directly to the container), it can help with [delegating event listeners](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate), and when targeting the elements via jQuery and CSS.
3. **why use `change` instead of `click` for checkboxes**

   `change` is the event specifically designed to trigger when a change of value occurs, `click` is designed to fire when a click occurs. You should use the event that best suits what you want. In this case you only wish to update when a checkbox has changed it's value, which can happen with or without a mouse. True, some browsers fire the `click` event when using keyboard events, but it is better to be clear.
4. **why use `data-ident`**

   ids should be used for quick look-up purposes, classes should be used to classify and group, if you have any other information to add to an element you should use the `data-` prefix. This means you aren't limited by what characters id and class support, and changing `data-` values doesn't cause any real internal calculations to fired by the browser i.e. applied classes or element registration.

#### how this code could be improved

The problem with making code more accessible and readable means that it's easier to work out what the code means, and this is bad for a game that should try and hide the solutions away from it's user-base. If this is just a simple game then there isn't much to worry about, but if you are working with something a bit more serious you should try and find a way to obfuscate the solutions :)

**working fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/RFK92/

**code:**

```
/// your list of what is checked
var checked = {};

var updateDivs = function(){
  var ident, show, checklist = [];
  /// create a useful string from what has been checked
  for ( ident in checked ) {
    if ( checked[ident] ) {
      checklist.push(ident);
    }
  }
  checklist = checklist.join(',');
  if ( checklist == '1,2,3' ) {
    show = $('#div1');
  }
  else if ( checklist == '1,2,4' ) {
    /// show something else, or not...
  } 
  /// by using a grouping class you can find all divs that could be affected
  $('.only-one-div').not(show).fadeOut();
  if ( show ) {
    /// and single one out for reveal
    show.fadeIn();
  }
};

$('.cb').change(function(){
  var cb = $(this), ident = cb.data('ident');
  /// keep track of what is or not checked
  checked[ident] = cb.prop('checked'); /// updated to use prop!
  /// update your divs
  updateDivs();
});
```

**markup:**

```
<div class="cbs">
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb cb1" data-ident="1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb cb2" data-ident="2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb cb3" data-ident="3" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb cb4" data-ident="4" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb cb5" data-ident="5" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="cb cb6" data-ident="6" />
</div>
<div id="div1" class="only-one-div">one</div>
<div id="div2" class="only-one-div">two</div>
```

**css:**

```
.only-one-div { display: none; }
```

Comment: I tried testing it, but no divs show up. Does it work for you?

Comment: @NoobCoder ~ I've added a working fiddle to show the concept in action. But that is all this is, a concept, you'll have to work it into the rest of your game code, including updating the markup... only then will things may work, but that doesn't take into account possible other interference from your existing code.

Comment: Going through it now, the comments help me understand what is going on a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @NoobCoder ~ Sure thing, I'll carry on updating my answer with further reasons as to why I've done certain things... which should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at binding and unbinding your clicks.

Basically, if they have clicked the first proper click then bind the second proper click.

Any incorrect clicks would have you unbind all the clicks and fadeOut the divs and rebind the first necessary click.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/CEb9x/1/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    if($('input:checked').length == 3){
        if ($('.blue:checked').length == 3) { $("#div1").fadeIn(); $("#div2").fadeOut();}
        else if ($('input[name="secret"]:checked').length == 3) { $("#div1").fadeOut(); $("#div2").fadeIn(); }
    } else { $("#div1, #div2").fadeOut(); }
  });
```

Comment: If you select any random three instead of 1,2,3, it will turn yellow

Comment: intentional, i assumed 1, 2, 4 is an example of anything other than 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
$("#1").click(function(){
    checkboxClicked();
});
$("#2").click(function(){
    checkboxClicked();
});
$("#3").click(function(){
    checkboxClicked();
});
$("#4").click(function(){
    checkboxClicked();
});
$("#5").click(function(){
    checkboxClicked();
});
$("#6").click(function(){
    checkboxClicked();
});
...
...
function checkboxClicked() {
    if ($('#1').is(':checked') && $('#2').is(':checked') && $('#3').is(':checked') {
        $('#div1').show();
        $('#div2').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#div1').hide();
    }
    if ($('#1').is(':checked') && $('#2').is(':checked') && $('#4').is(':checked') {
        $('#div2').show();
        $('#div1').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#div2').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you just gave all the buttons the same class. This way you would only need to define 1 click event.

Comment: What are the "..."s in place of?

Comment: Jesus! They are some other pieces of code you may have after registering the click event handlers.

Comment: sorry when I tried running it, it didn't work so I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something